# Set cell backgroundColor when selected - Swift

Tags: colors, swift, cell

Here on stackOverflow I found a method that will allow iOS users to **update the default "Selected" color of a tableCell.**
Now, how to do the same on OS X, using Swift ?

Code working for iOS:

```
var bgColorView = UIView()
bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
cell.setSelectedBackgroundView = bgColorView
```

I tried to change the code for OS X purposes.. Without success

```
//Set selected color of cell
    var bgColorView = NSView()
    bgColorView.backgroundColor = NSColor.redColor()
    cell.setSelectedBackgroundView = bgColorView
```

This are the errors i get
[image: Errors image]

Thank you all. Alberto.

Comment: Please replace the screenshot with actual text of the errors.

Comment: Excuse me? I don't understand.. The errors are there highlited in red

Comment: This site is mostly text based. Please remove the screenshot and actually *type in* the errors so that they are actually readable and can be found with a search.

Answer (score 0):

var myBackView=UIView(frame:cell.frame)

myBackView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();

cell.selectedBackgroundView = myBackView;

Comment: UIView ? That is iOS not OSX

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.YellowColor()
```

This lines goes after `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Have you read the question? Why you mention UI if I asked for OS X ? (NS)

Comment: cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()